# TDBGrid not saving TColumn.Width property after Visible := false

Tags: delphi, tdbgrid

When saving a form with a TDBGrid having a column with Visible = false, the column's Width property is not saved, and the original value of the Width property is lost.

The context is a [TColumn](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/Vcl.DBGrids.TColumn) in a standard VCL [TDBGrid](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/Vcl.DBGrids.TDBGrid) control on a form (Delphi 10.1 Berlin). If the Visible property of the column is set to false in the object inspector, the Width property immediately goes to -1. Setting Visible back to true, restores the previous value of Width.

However, if the form is saved while the column's Visible property is false, and the form is closed and reopened, then the same column's Visible property is set to true again, the Width always comes back as 163839. This of course hides any other columns to the right, and messes up scrolling, which rightly confuses non-technical users.

I suspect it is a VCL bug, since the property getter for the TColumn.Width property (in unit Vcl.DBGrids) is as follows:

```pascal
unit Vcl.DBGrids;
...
function TColumn.GetWidth: Integer;
begin
  if not Showing then      // depends on Visible property
    Result := -1           // obviously streamed to .DFM
  else if cvWidth in FAssignedValues then
    Result := FWidth
  else
    Result := DefaultWidth;
end;
```

[image]

**Is this a VCL bug, or am I using it wrong?**

PS: does this have anything to do with TColumn.[AssignedValues](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/Vcl.DBGrids.TColumn.AssignedValues)? Or is the built-in Delphi DBGrid just flawed.

**Edit:** My app allows the user to resize, reorder and show/hide columns in a main results grid at run-time, but also to restore back to defaults. I'm using the grid at design-time as the "master" when restoring defaults, i.e. default column widths and order, and also which columns are visible by default. But losing the column Width for columns hidden by default is messing with that.

Comment: It is a bug. You must be allowed to hide the column and have it hidden when you close and open your project.